# How to align the placeholder to center alignment in ion-input?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

How to align the placeholder to center alignment in ion-input ????

[this is my ionic input fields in left alignments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWG4u.png)

i tried to move center alignment, but i could't , please tell me anyone the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS file with your tag add this to align placeholder text in the center.

**Tag:**

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Type something"></ion-input>
```

**Design:**

```
ion-input::placeholder{
    text-align: center;
}
```

try this it should work.

Comment: sir i used ur code but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should find the element classes with browser's developer tools and make your changes to them. Add this to your css file:

```
.native-input::placeholder{
  text-align: center;
}
```

or you can use a class in your html file if you don't want it to apply to all of your inputs in the page:

```
.my-input .native-input::placeholder{
  text-align: center;
}
```